# What happens on the primary when log cannot be restored on the secondary on Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, high-availability, log-shipping

I would like to setup a log shipping but I have a concern as to what would happen if the restore operation on the secondary would fail for some reason. I want the primary database keep working no matter what happens on the secondary database - even if the log restore can't be completed or secondary db goes offline. Does log shipping offer such an option?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restore failing on the secondary will have no impact on the primary. You want to monitor your secondary DBs to make sure this hasn't happened.

Comment: Thank you James. Does log shipping work this way by nature or is there an alternate switch to setup synchronous working like mirroring? Thank you.

Comment: Log shipping is not a replication feature, it's a method of replicating databases. All you are doing is backing up the primary and restoring the backup somewhere else. The primary doesn't even know the secondary exists. You can't have synchronous log shipping.

Comment: It might have an impact if you use data guard and maximum protection. Which is not the default option for data guard. You want maximum availability if you are using data guard. In that case Oracle keeps track of the logs that have not shipped and will ship them, if they are available, once the standby database is accepting archive logs.